# Smart Suggest Expanded Search Match

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, autosuggest

I bought and implemented "Smart Suggest", but my visitors are often not getting results for partial matches.  Please see my example below for specifics on my problem.

Does anyone have an idea on how to make the suggestions more broadly matched?

1. Visit: www.jwsuretybonds.com
2. Type in “California contractor”
3. Notice 3 results, with the 1st being: “California Contractor License Performance & Payment Bond”
4. Now type in “California contractor payment” and note 0 results.  I’d like that first result to still show.
5. Now type in “california payment contractor” and note 0 results.  I’d like that first result to still show.

Comment: please provide more details about the actual implementation of your Smart Search solution

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you actually mean when you say that you've "bought and implemented Smart Suggest" but the functionality you're describing is usually achieved by means of using [full text indexes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_text_search), that's if you're using an RDBMS to store the suggested values. For MySQL see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html).

One more option would be to use some separate software solution like [ElasticSearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/) which in my opinion is justified only if you've got a really big number of such texts and you are using them for more than just a simple suggest box.

Another option would be to actually adjust your existing algorithm to use Regular Expressions or something else to actually do what you want it to do.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Yervand.  I'll attempt to clarify further...I bought "Smart Suggest" at: http://jamesskidmore.com/scripts/smartsuggest/                           I suppose I need to edit the Javascript I have (http://www.jwsuretybonds.com/js/jquery.smartsuggest.js) to do regular expressions, but I don't know Javascript, just PHP.

Comment: you don't need to change anything in JS. when a person types anything in the suggest box the SmartSuggest javascript does an AJAX call to the server with GET parameter q which contains the text currently filled in the suggest box. At least the demonstration on the page you linked works that very way. So what you need is to actually correctly implement your server side PHP code to filter and return the items you need to be displayed.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to where the issue is Yervand!  I was barking up the wrong tree w/ the Javascript I guess.  I'll see if I can modify the SQL statement.